# Вывести переменную название которой равно значению другой переменной js

Tags: javascript, строки, переменные

Предположим есть переменная `lol` значение которой равно тому что ввели в `input`, в базе находятся переменные и мне нужно вывести значение переменной название которой равно значению переменной `lol`
Например:
В `input` ввели `superman` т.е. `lol="superman"`, мне нужно вывести переменную название которой равно `superman`. База представляет собой js файл.

Comment: Может быть покажете фрагмент вашей "базы"? Это сильно поможет.

Comment: Вот пример базы:
var lolman="lolman it's jokeman";
superman="superman help people"

Comment: @Perkovec ну объявите это так:

    var db={
       lolman: "lolman it's jokeman",
       superman: "superman help people"
    };

Comment: Json не подходит, проверил.

Comment: Решил по другому

Comment: @Perkovec, это не json, это просто объект.

Comment: Я сделал всё так: шифрую введённое слово в числовое значение и прошу вывести например human[4527471] (superman) а база выглядит так 

var human= new Array();
human[35371531]='lolman it's jokeman'
human[4527471]='superman help people'

Comment: omg, зачем чем вас не устраивает human['superman'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути все переменные в javascript - это свойства каких-либо объектов, например глобальные переменные - свойства объекта window. Следовательно к ним можно обращаться по имени как к свойствам объектов. 
Например window[lol] или window ['superman'] если мы ищем в глобальном контексте, obj[lol] - контексте obj;

Comment: @Volt не совсем правда, например локальная переменная variable заданная вот так:

    (function(){
        var variable="value";
    })()

не является свойством какого-либо объекта. (кроме scope, доступа к которому нет)